# How can I get timestamps in Perl DBI logfiles?

Tags: perl, logging, dbi

I have an issue where an application is randomly dying during a DBI call. We cannot reliably reproduce this in our test or acceptance environment, so I am required to monitor it on our production system to try to figure out what is happening.

I am logging all the `DBI` traffic via the `DBI_TRACE` environment variable.

```
DBI_TRACE=3=dbi.log script.pl
```

The issue is however that there are no time stamps in the DBI log files, so it is difficult to go back through them to find what was occurring at the time of the die.

Is there any way to enable logging of DBI with time stamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBI documentation [contains](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm#Tracing_to_Layered_Filehandles) code how to enable timestamped logs using layered file-handles. The downside is that you lose the luxury of using environment variables, and have to set tracing parameters in code:

```
$dbh->trace('SQL', $fh);
```

Where $fh holds reference to the object which is 'subclass' of [PerlIO::Via](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.7.3/ext/PerlIO/Via/Via.pm)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [File::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/File-Tee/lib/File/Tee.pm) to redirect STDERR and add a prefix with the timestamp.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Tee 'tee';

my $logfile = "/path/to/timestamped/logfile.log";
my $filter  = sub { return localtime() . ' ' . $_[0] };

my $pid = tee STDERR, { preprocess => $filter, reopen => $logfile };

print STDERR "something bad happened.";
```

The advantage here is that it won't interfere with your existing STDERR -- all error messages will continue to go to the same place. But the stream is duplicated and also written to `$logfile`, with whatever transformation you want via the `$filter` hook.

Answer (score 2):

If overriding `STDERR` isn't an option, and if you're on a UNIXy system (which various posts suggest you are), you might direct the trace output to a [fifo](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_163) and run a timestamping filter there:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo
$ perl -MTime::HiRes=time -npe 's/^/time . " "/e' < /tmp/fifo > /tmp/timestamped.log &
[1] 12345
$ DBI_TRACE=1=/tmp/fifo script.pl
```

That filtering program could be anything, even [logger](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logger.html), which on my system adds timestamps courtesy of *syslogd*.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look into [DBI::Log](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI::Log).

By default it prints to STDERR so to replicate your usage you call it like this:

> perl -MDBI::Log script.pl 2> dbi.log

The output gives you a much better overall picture of what happened in your DBI based SQL access by:

- containing **timestamps**,
- replacing **placeholders** (aka. bound parameters) with actual values which makes rerunning the queries directly in SQL easier for debugging, and
- containing **call traces** of the Perl code that led to the respective SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a problem in DBI itself although it is possible. DBI's tracing can be very verbose although I see you are using trace level 3. Use DBIx::Log4perl and you'll get configurable timestamps, method call, SQL, binding etc tracing and all you need to do is change your connect call.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a minimalistic [perl logger](http://code.google.com/p/perlminlogger/) with configurable dynamic logging giving you the following API:

```
        use strict ; use warnings ; use Exporter;
        use Configurator ; 
        use Logger ; 


        #   anonymous hash !!!
        our $confHolder = () ; 

        sub main {

                # strip the remote path and keep the bare name
                $0=~m/^(.*)(\\|\/)(.*)\.([a-z]*)/; 
                my $MyBareName = $3; 
                my $RunDir= $1 ; 

                # create the configurator object 
                my $objConfigurator = new Configurator($RunDir , $MyBareName ); 
                # get the hash having the vars 
                $confHolder = $objConfigurator ->getConfHolder () ; 
                # pring the hash vars 
                print $objConfigurator->dumpIni();  

                my $objLogger = new Logger (\$confHolder) ; 
                $objLogger->LogMsg  (   " START MAIN " ) ;  

                $objLogger->LogMsg  (   "my \$RunDir is $RunDir" ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogMsg  (   "this is a simple message" ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogErrorMsg (   "This is an error message " ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogWarningMsg   (   "This is a warning message " ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogInfoMsg  (   "This is a info message " ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogDebugMsg (   "This is a debug message " ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogTraceMsg (   "This is a trace message " ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogMsg  (   "using the following log file " .  "$confHolder->{'LogFile'}" ) ; 
                $objLogger->LogMsg  (   " STOP MAIN \n\n" ) ; 

        } #eof main 



        #Action !!!
        main(); 

        1 ; 

        __END__
```

Comment: 'Configurator' and 'Logger' are horrible package names. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Guidelines-for-Module-Creation